# Paypal Webhook Event for card expiracy in a subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I would be pleased to know what is the webhook event fired by Paypal when, during a subscription, a payment fails (not at the subscription creation but at its renewal).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.PAYMENT.FAILED`

The most straightforward solution is to simply base all logic on `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`.  If you don't receive one on time for a subscription, then it has lapsed.

---

Adding a `custom_id` when a subscription is first created can be useful for reconciliation.